# Add side menu for page

Tags: html, css

So I'm creating a site for Japanese study, and I want to add a side menu to my page. I'm having trouble getting the second unordered list to run down the page INSIDE the white area of the quiz section on the right side. Something similar to this website:

https://japanesetest4you.com/jlpt-n1-grammar-exercise-26/

What is the best way to go about this? I've tried various things but haven't had much luck. This is my HTML:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #58c6d7;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #58c6d7;
}

.body_color {
  background-color: #def7fb;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sns_box {
  color: black;
}

.sns_box:hover {
  color: #8332AB;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sns_btn {
  width: 280px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid #8332AB;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sns_btn:before {
  content: "FOLLOW US";
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #8332AB;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sns_btn:hover {
  background: #FFF
}

.sns_btn:hover:before {
  top: -50%;
}

.logo {
  border-color: #333;
  width: 150px;
}

.logo_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quiz_space {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #333;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu_text {
  border: 3px #def7fb;
  font-size: 16px;
  s
}

.instructions {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.question_spacing {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.advert_space {
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.side_container_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="advert_space">

  <body class="body_color">
    <div class="logo_container">
      <div class="flex_logo">
        <img class="logo" src="Home Page Logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="top_menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn">Select Level</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">N5</a>
        <a href="#">N4</a>
        <a href="#">N3</a>
        <a href="#">N2</a>
        <a href="#">N1</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="quiz_space">
      <div class="side_menu_container">
        <h3>Learn Japanese Through Popular Culture</h3>
        <ul class="side_menu">
          <a href="">Anime</a>
          <a href="">Songs</a>
          <a href="">TV Shows</a>
          <a href="">Manga</a>
          <a href="">Blogs</a>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <p class="questions" id="question1">
        <b> 1. 小説がベストセラーになってから、彼は毎日<u>執筆</u>で忙しくなった</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="wrong"><span>しゅっぴつ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="correct"><span>しっぴつ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="wrong"><span>しっしょ</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question2">
        <b> 2. 彼女は度胸を<u>据えて</u>部長の部屋に入った</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="wrong"><span>とらえて</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="wrong"><span>そなえて</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="correct"><span>すえて</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question3">
        <b> 3. 時間<u>厳守</u>は最低限度のマナーである</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="wrong"><span>ぎんしゅ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="wrong"><span>きんしゅ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="correct"><span>げんしゅ</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question4">
        <b>4. 海は<u>穏やか</u>に見えるとはいえ、実際強い急流が流れている</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="wrong"><span>なめらか</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="correct"><span>おだやか</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="wrong"><span>あざやか</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question5">
        <b>５. 合計が高いと思ったから<u>内訳</u>を確認した</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question6">
        <b>6. 台風を抜け出したと聞いた彼女は<u>安堵</u>のため息をもらした</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question7">
        <b> 7. この雑誌は不安を<u>煽る</u>記事ばかりでわざわざ読む必要はないと思う</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question8">
        <b> 8. 彼は先生のことを<u>仰いでいる</u></b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question9">
        <b>9. ドイツに行ってみたいと<u>かねがね</u>思っていました。</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <p class="questions" id="question10">
        <b> 10. テレワークが増えているので自分の<u>書斎</u>を求めている人が多い</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>

      <button class="submit" onclick="return getResults();" type="submit">
      Check answers</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button>Download PDF</button>

      <h2 id="results-h">Results</h2>
      <p id="results"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="sns_btn">
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square"></i></a>
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
        <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

I tried using flexboxes and grids, but I couldn't quite get the effect I wanted

Answer (score 1):

I'm fixed mistakes in html, after this wrapped questions in container `.quiz_space__content`  and add for parent(`.quiz_space`) css `display: flex`.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.top_menu li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #58c6d7;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #58c6d7;
}

.body_color {
  background-color: #def7fb;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.sns_box {
  color: black;
}

.sns_box:hover {
  color: #8332AB;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sns_btn {
  width: 280px;
  height: 60px;
  border: 3px solid #8332AB;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 24px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sns_btn:before {
  content: "FOLLOW US";
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #8332AB;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sns_btn:hover {
  background: #FFF
}

.sns_btn:hover:before {
  top: -50%;
}

.logo {
  border-color: #333;
  width: 150px;
}

.logo_container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.quiz_space {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 3px solid;
  border-color: #333;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
}

.menu_text {
  border: 3px #def7fb;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.instructions {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

label {
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.question_spacing {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.advert_space {
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.side_container_menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
}

.quiz_space {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.side_menu {
  max-width: 220px;
}

.quiz_space__content {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="advert_space">

  <div class="logo_container">
    <div class="flex_logo">
      <img class="logo" src="Home Page Logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top_menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Select Level</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">N5</a>
      <a href="#">N4</a>
      <a href="#">N3</a>
      <a href="#">N2</a>
      <a href="#">N1</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="quiz_space">
    <div class="side_menu_container">
      <h3>Learn Japanese Through Popular Culture</h3>
      <ul class="side_menu">
        <a href="">Anime</a>
        <a href="">Songs</a>
        <a href="">TV Shows</a>
        <a href="">Manga</a>
        <a href="">Blogs</a>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="quiz_space__content">
      <p class="questions" id="question1">
        <b> 1. 小説がベストセラーになってから、彼は毎日<u>執筆</u>で忙しくなった</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="wrong"><span>しゅっぴつ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="correct"><span>しっぴつ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer1" value="wrong"><span>しっしょ</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question2">
        <b> 2. 彼女は度胸を<u>据えて</u>部長の部屋に入った</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="wrong"><span>とらえて</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="wrong"><span>そなえて</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer2" value="correct"><span>すえて</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question3">
        <b> 3. 時間<u>厳守</u>は最低限度のマナーである</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="wrong"><span>ぎんしゅ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="wrong"><span>きんしゅ</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer3" value="correct"><span>げんしゅ</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question4">
        <b>4. 海は<u>穏やか</u>に見えるとはいえ、実際強い急流が流れている</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="wrong"><span>なめらか</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="correct"><span>おだやか</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer4" value="wrong"><span>あざやか</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question5">
        <b>５. 合計が高いと思ったから<u>内訳</u>を確認した</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer5" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question6">
        <b>6. 台風を抜け出したと聞いた彼女は<u>安堵</u>のため息をもらした</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer6" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question7">
        <b> 7. この雑誌は不安を<u>煽る</u>記事ばかりでわざわざ読む必要はないと思う</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer7" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question8">
        <b> 8. 彼は先生のことを<u>仰いでいる</u></b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer8" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question9">
        <b>9. ドイツに行ってみたいと<u>かねがね</u>思っていました。</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer9" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <p class="questions" id="question10">
        <b> 10. テレワークが増えているので自分の<u>書斎</u>を求めている人が多い</b></p>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="correct"><span>Real Madrid</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="wrong"><span>F.C. Barcelona</span>
      <input type="radio" name="answer10" value="wrong"><span>A.C. Milano</span>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button class="submit" onclick="return getResults();" type="submit">
              Check answers</button>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button>Download PDF</button>
      <h2 id="results-h">Results</h2>
      <p id="results"></p>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sns_btn">
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github-square"></i></a>
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-codepen"></i></a>
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play"></i></a>
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square"></i></a>
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square"></i></a>
      <a class="sns_box" href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```